# Does Bitcoin script support nested IFs (OP_IF or OP_NOTIF inside one another)?

Tags: script

For example can we convert the following code to a script?

```
if(bool_1)
{
    FOO1();
    if(!bool_2)
    {
        FOO2();
    }
    else
    {
        BAR1();
        if(bool_3)
        {
            BAR2();
        }
        BAR3();
    }
}
else
{
    FOOBAR();
}
```

`<push> <push> <push> OP_IF OP_FOO1 OP_NOTIF OP_FOO2 OP_ELSE OP_BAR1 OP_IF OP_BAR2 OP_ENDIF OP_BAR3 OP_ENDIF OP_FOOBAR OP_ENDIF`(correct?)

If yes then:
1. Is there any limit on how deep a nested IFs can go?
2. Is there any examples (raw bytes/hex) I could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do bitcoin scripts support nested ifs (OP_IF OP_NOTIF inside one another)?

Yes, Bitcoin support nested IF/ELSE. In fact we use the nested IFs in Lightning Network all the time when adding HTLCs to forward a payment.

> Is there any limit on how deep a nested if can go?

There is no explicit rules dictating how far deep the nested IFs can go but [there are some constrains](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script.h) on the script itself:

- Maximum number of bytes pushable to the stack should be less than 520 bytes
- Maximum operations per script is limited to 201
- Maximum size of the script is 10,000 bytes
- Maximum number of values on script interpreter stack is 1,000 bytes

> Is there any examples (raw bytes/hex) I could look at?

As I mentioned earlier, we use nested IFs all the time while adding HTLCs in the Lightning Network implementation. Below is an output script of [offered HTLC outputs](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#offered-htlc-outputs) for a peer.

```
# To remote node with revocation key
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(SHA256(revocationpubkey))> OP_EQUAL
OP_IF
    OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ELSE
    <remote_htlcpubkey> OP_SWAP OP_SIZE 32 OP_EQUAL
    OP_NOTIF
        # To local node via HTLC-timeout transaction (timelocked).
        OP_DROP 2 OP_SWAP <local_htlcpubkey> 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
    OP_ELSE
        # To remote node with preimage.
        OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(payment_hash)> OP_EQUALVERIFY
        OP_CHECKSIG
    OP_ENDIF
OP_ENDIF
```

Comment: `IF/ELSE loops` Is "loop" the correct term to use?

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast thanks for correcting. I wrote the answer from my phone.